# How to create vector<Mat>?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I try to run this code to crate a `vector<Mat>`

```
vector<Mat> scoreImgs(8, Mat(size, CV_32FC1));
```

I found it was not deep copy. I don't want to use `for` or `while` like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) 
{
    scoreImgs[i] = move(Mat(size, CV_32FC1));
}
```

So how can I create a `vector<Mat>` with deep copy.

Comment: How did you find _it was not deep copy_?

Comment: @Scheff this is nature of OpenCV library. `Mat` in works more like smart pointer to matrix.

Comment: @MarekR Yepp. I just found the doc. about the copy constructor [cv::Mat::Mat(const Mat&)](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
vector<Mat> scoreImgs;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(scoreImgs), 8,
                []() { return Mat(size, CV_32FC1); });
```

It might be useful to write helper function:

```cpp
std::vector<Mat> vectorOfNClonedCvMat(cv::Mat toClone, size_t n)
{
    std::vector<Mat> r;
    r.reserve(n);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(r), n,
                    [&toClone]() { return toClone.clone(); });
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have same values to be initialized for all the objects you are creating, then answer by Merek R is good way.

alternatively you can simply use `emplace_back()` method for `std::vector` I assume you would have different values to be initialized for 8 different objects you are instantiating so I used for loop below to demonstrate.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define CV_32FC1 100

class Mat {
    public:
        Mat(int size, int cv) {}
        ~Mat() {}
};

int main()
{
    int size = 50;
    std::vector<Mat> scoreImgs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        scoreImgs.emplace_back(size, CV_32FC1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wrote: `I don't want to use for or while like`.

Comment: yes that's true. In that case your proposed solution is to the point. I am just providing a solution where you don't have to use `new` operator

Comment: Thanks for your help. My goal is to allocate space in advance for subsequent code. I'm looking for a simple and efficient way.